# How we can use Scroll page without scroll bar and In my page i Have to do scrolling in half page only

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

1.I am Using web driver for scrolling in page i have to scroll after half page to bottom. 
2. The scroll bar will not come and before scroll i have to click in second part of application then only i can scroll. 
3. Whole page does not support scrolling

Comment: Got any code for what you've tried so far/where is your code getting stuck?

Comment: I tried in my code but i am not able to do can u give some example of code.

Comment: @Josh can u tell me what  code you use for scrolling

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find any code of scrolling then you can try to focus where you want by using below code:
hope this will help.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').focus()");
```